# What is the purpose of knowing the relation between Nusselt number and Rayleigh number for free convection

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I am a physics student, and during a laboratory work, I had to evaluate both Nusselt and Rayleigh numbers for a free convection experiment, and then find a relation

$$Nu = \alpha \cdot Ra^\beta $$

In which is knowing this relation useful ? (Because it seems to depend a lot on the geometry of the problem, so I can't use it in another free convection experiment).

Comment: For the geometry you are dealing with, it enables you to predict the rate of heat transfer from the object to the surrounding fluid under all sets of operating conditions, and for all scale versions of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Nusselt number tells the heat transfer. Rayleigh number tells you the free convection flow condition (velocity, density etc.). We know the stronger the flow, the more heat exchange can likely be involved. It might not be linear and might not be even in power formula.We do this test to establish this relationship.